# Google Street View location not changing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is a link to what I'm working on (code also included at the end): http://urloritdidnthappen.appspot.com/1557001

Here is a link to a jsFiddle I made that has the same error (slightly different code but the problem is the same):
http://jsfiddle.net/stealthiskarl/sNfd2/1/

What it's supposed to do is if you click on different rooms, it takes you to different rooms.  However, when I'm changing the latitude and longitude of the street view inside the building, it doesn't do anything.  It always ends up taking me to the same spot inside the building.

If you notice, the starting lat/lng is:

```
LatLng(40.75506,-73.999696)
```

And then when you click on the room at the top right, the lat and lng is:

```
LatLng(40.755043,-73.999653)
```

So it should take you to a different place... but it doesn't!  However, when you click the room on the bottom left (for testing purposes it sends you right outside the building), it sends you to:

```
LatLng(40.754802,-73.999657)
```

which works propperly.  Is there a way to fix this so my lat/lng values actually work when inside the building? If it helps, [here is a link](https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&ll=40.754934,-73.999585&spn=0.005234,0.010514&sll=40.755115,-73.999661&layer=c&cid=15038076762535818547&panoid=jjzaFfJHhoEAAAQJOMAhDA&cbp=13,249.48,,0,0&gl=US&t=m&z=17&cbll=40.754934,-73.999585) to the location on Street View that I'm working with.

Thanks

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOXB3qYYiL7NpxucBIEDq9CX5DlyiL5Ns&sensor=false"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var map;

        function initialize() {
            var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75506, -73.999696);
            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                    heading: 263,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoramaOptions);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: fenway,
                zoom: 14,
                streetView: panoramaOptions
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        function moveToRoom(roomNumber) {
            var fenway;
            if (roomNumber == 1)
                fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(40.755043, -73.999653);
            else
                fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(40.754802, -73.999657);
            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                    heading: 263,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            };
            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoramaOptions);
            map.setStreetView(panorama);

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>

    <div style="position:relative;width=454px; height=206px">
        <img src="http://location05.com/images/floorplan_preview.jpg" alt="floorplan" style="position: absolute; z-index:-1;" />
        <div style="absolute; z-index:0; padding-top:8px; padding-left:285px;">
            <img src="http://location05.com/images/sample_floorplan_overlay.png" alt="floorplan" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" 
            onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" 
            onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0"
            onclick="moveToRoom(1);" />
        </div>
        <div style="absolute; z-index:0; padding-top:59px; padding-left:31px;">
            <img src="http://location05.com/images/sample_floorplan_overlay.png" alt="floorplan" style="opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0)" 
            onmouseover="this.style.opacity=1;this.filters.alpha.opacity=100" 
            onmouseout="this.style.opacity=0;this.filters.alpha.opacity=0"
            onclick="moveToRoom(2);" />
        </div>

    </div>

    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 562px; height: 314px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't just link to an external site, include your code in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask _"also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."_  - I can't access your app without giving it permission to connect to my Google account

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Also, I was going to use jsFiddle (which doesn't require logging into a Google account) but for some reason the Google Maps API key code didn't work for it.  That key code may make it hard to test the straight code, let me know if there is anything else I can do to make the question better.  Thanks again, Karl.

Comment: you should be able to just omit the API key

Comment: You're right.  I just finished making a jsFiddle for the question. I've edited the question to include it. The code is slightly different from the code I was using before, but it has the same problem, so it should have the same solution.  Thanks again duncan.